# The performance concern of AES (RijndaelManaged) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I intend to encrypt large data (around 3-5 MB) with **RijndaelManaged**. Is there any performance issue\suggestion on doing so?

Thanks

```
        RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 128;
        rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 128;
```

Comment: I think 3–5 MiB is quite small for today's standards.

Comment: I don't think you can blink fast enough :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I can safely say there will not be any performance issues. Here's what I timed (And this includes some disk access:

`00:00:00.26 seconds for 2MB`

Like I said faster than you can blink: [see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink)